# Retrieving GeoPoint array from Firestore Database add map polygon

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After searching for a few days across StackOverflow groups I have been able to come up with the below coding which is a combination of items found for retrieving geopoint arrays from Firestore and also items for displaying polygons on Android googleMap. The activity loads and there are no errors however the polygon does not seem to be showing; I believe it is the List Object that is the issue as the QueryDocuementSnapshot works fine for when I add normal markers to the map from different documents. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
private void addPolygonsToMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference pProfileRef = db.collection("polygons");
    pProfileRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    List<Object> polyPoint=(List<Object>)document.get("points"); for (Object geoObject : polyPoint) {
                        int length = polyPoint.size();
                        if(length ==0){
                            return;
                        }
                        PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();
                        poly.fillColor(0x4d4fa5d5);
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            poly.add(new LatLng(polyPoint.get(i).a, polyPoint.get(i).b));
                        }
                        googleMap.addPolygon(poly);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents:", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then in my onMapReady I have.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
       // polyMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Location");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        //googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(18.0f);
        //googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(6.0f);
        addMarkersToMap(googleMap);
        addPolygonsToMap(googleMap);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Set a listener for marker click.
        //googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }
```

Screenshot of Firebase database as requested
[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Alex - edited with database structure as requested. After discussions today I believe potentially I require a loop for my array list whereas at the moment I am only calling one point. Thank you for looking into this for me.

Comment: This is what you need to loop through the entire array and get those geopoints.

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry I can't see anything other than your comment "This is what you need to loop through the entire array and get those geopoints." was there any code following that? Thanks, Craig

Comment: No worries, just doing that now. Thought I would just check to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated to include my coding for loop, I fear I am missing something rather easy and in plain sight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out the loop and code as below.

Adapting knowledge of placing markers and combining with stackoverflow topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116134/drawing-polygons-on-google-map-using-array-android).

```
private void addPolygonsToMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference pProfileRef = db.collection("polygons");
        pProfileRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        List<Object> polyPoint=(List<Object>)document.get("points");
                                int length = polyPoint.size();
                                if (length == 0) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();
                                poly.fillColor(0x4d4fa5d5);
                                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                                    GeoPoint polyGeo = (GeoPoint) polyPoint.get(i);
                                    double lat = polyGeo.getLatitude();
                                    double lng = polyGeo.getLongitude ();
                                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                    poly.add(latLng);
                                }
                                googleMap.addPolygon(poly);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents:", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```